# Can I craft armor in Minecraft Earth?

Tags: minecraft-earth

I've just started performing Adventures near my house in Minecraft Earth and I am quickly finding out how fragile my character is. One or two skeletons is more than a match for my character and I can't seem out-damage them before they can defeat me.

I need armor, I need something that will let me live long enough to survive an encounter with a hostile skeleton. Is it possible to craft armor in Minecraft Earth? If not, is there any other way to increase my health or heal during Adventures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's currently no armor options in MCE. You can eat food to regain health and that's pretty much it. My strategy is to remove blocks carefully so I can control how much I have to deal with hostile mobs at once. You can use blocks as barriers to hide behind while recovering HP. Swords/fists have unlimited range so if you see their legs, top of the head, or something you can hack them to bits without them being able to get off a shot at you.